# How to replace line with the yanked one multiple time?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

In many cases, I have to replace a line by another in multiple places.

I can yank my desired line, go do the replacement location, do a `pdd`, move on, and of course I don't have the same line available for pasting.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: may be this answer can help you [Stop Vim from yanking visual selected text](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37251/23502)

Comment: also see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34850/is-it-possible-to-properly-repeat-a-visual-replacement

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you grabbed the first line with a `y` command, it should be in register 0. So you can do `"0pdd` every time (or, `let @q = '"0pdd'` and run `@q`/`@@` for slightly less typing).

If the target lines are all in the same buffer as the original line, you can use a command like

```
:[from line]copy [to line] | [to line]delete
```

For example: `:2copy 5 | 5delete`. We can even wrap like this:

```
:command -nargs=1 -range Replace mark ' | <line1>,<line2>copy <args> | '' | <args>delete
```

where the range argument to `Replace` determines what line(s) to copy, defaulting to the current line, and the argument gives and address for the target (which is then deleted). The extra `mark '` and `''` commands resets the current line to its current position when starting the `:delete`, since an address (`<args>`, here) can be a search pattern and we want to make sure both uses target the same line.

Starting with

```
a
b
a
c
d
```

we have the following examples:

1. `gg:2Replace /a/` turns the second `a` line into `b`
2. `G:Replace 4` turns the `c` line into `d`.
3. `:1,3Replace 4` turns the line 4 into multiple lines.
   etc.

Note that arguments like `$`, whose actual line number changes after executing `copy`, may behave unexpectedly. (Perhaps deleting first would help?)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `pdd`, simply select the line you want to be replaced with `V` and then use `P`. That's it.

The reason to use the upper-case `P` instead of `p` is that it preserves registers, allowing you to do the same again.

Note that upper case P is a recent feature, around patch 8.2.4881.

Comment: I think you want to use `VP` instead of `Vp`

Comment: Right, thanks for correction. I haven't sleep this night.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer covers how to replace a line with contents of a register.  However, you'll find with doing `VP`, you'll lose the ability to repeat it via `.`.

I maintain a very small plugin which solves this visual put repeat problem.

https://github.com/andymass/vim-visput